# AWS EC2 instance name is hyphenated

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-aws, terraform0.12+, terraform-aws-modules

I am using the following terraform to create windows EC2 instance. The instance is launched successfully, but in AWS console I see hyphenated name for EC2 instance.
For brevity purpose I have removed some TF code

[image]

```
resource "aws_launch_template" "server_launch_template" {  
  name          = "my-launch-template"
  image_id      = "my-windows-ami-id"
  instance_type = "t3.medium"
  key_name      = "my-keypair"

  vpc_security_group_ids = [var.security_group_id]  

  iam_instance_profile {
    arn = aws_iam_instance_profile.my_instance.arn
  }   

  tag_specifications {
    resource_type = "instance"
    tags          = module.tags.mytags
  }

  lifecycle {
    create_before_destroy = true
  }
}

resource "aws_autoscaling_group" "server_autoscaling_group" {  
  name                      = "my autoscaling group"
  max_size                  = 1
  min_size                  = 1
  desired_capacity          = 1
  vpc_zone_identifier       = [var.subnet_id]
  wait_for_capacity_timeout = var.wait_for_capacity

  health_check_type = "EC2"

  dynamic "tag" {
    #some code here
  }

  launch_template {
    id      = aws_launch_template.server_launch_template.id
    version = "$Latest"
  }

  lifecycle {
    create_before_destroy = true
  }  
}
```

How and where do I specify instance name in the launch template?

Comment: EC2 instances get their name from the `Name` tag I think.

Comment: @MarkoE is correct. Other cloud platforms e.g. GCP and AZR have specific name paramaeters, but AWS uses the `name` tag.

Comment: @MarkoE You are correct. I had to add `Name` key in `aws_launch_template`'s  `tag_specifications` attribute

Answer (score 1):

You can't define dynamic names for instances launched by an autoscaling group.

You can however configure a lambda function to run whenever the autoscaling launches new instances, and you can name the instances from the lambda.

Comment: @lp13 it is correct. and if you want the instances to have different names, it's the only way you can do it

Comment: That's not "the only way". You can also configure a user-data script so that the instance sets its own name on startup. That's the method I used before Lambda even existed.

Comment: @MarkB and how is that going to work if you have more than one instance, and if OP wants different names for them?

Comment: @Paolo Why do you think it would work any differently from the Lambda function you recommend? In either case you would be running the same code to set the `Name` tag on the EC2 instance.

Comment: @MarkB that's true, but would you really recommend that as a solution?

Comment: How is it any worse than your solution? Yes I would absolutely recommend it.

Comment: @MarkB really? lambda functions can be versioned, they have Cloudwatch logging out of the box, etc.

Comment: You said Lambda is the "only" solution, I'm just correcting that statement. As for recommending EC2 user-data instead of a Lambda function, the infrastructure already exists for the EC2 user-data to run, versus having to setup and maintain a Lambda function, with the appropriate IAM role, Event Bridge triggers, etc. The Lambda function also eats into your account's maximum concurrent functions quota. If you are working in an environment where you have to get every new piece of infrastructure approved by a security team, the EC2 method is much easier.

Comment: @markb you're right, I should have said "it's the only good solution"

Answer (score 1):

This works. As @MarkoE suggested added `Name` tag in `tag_specifications`

```
resource "aws_launch_template" "server_launch_template" {  
  name          = "my-launch-template"
  image_id      = "my-windows-ami-id"
  instance_type = "t3.medium"
  key_name      = "my-keypair"

  vpc_security_group_ids = [var.security_group_id]  

  iam_instance_profile {
    arn = aws_iam_instance_profile.my_instance.arn
  }   

  tag_specifications {
    resource_type = "instance"
    tags          = merge(module.tags.mytags, { Name = "my-runner-instance" })
  }

  lifecycle {
    create_before_destroy = true
  }
}
```

Comment: So is your autoscaling group only going to have one instance?